# How to align items to left (header)

Tags: html, css, header

I'm trying to align some items to the left, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
I'm making the youtube header, and at this time, I've done this

[image]

I got to align the first two items to the right with a simple padding, but when it comes to the left side of the header, nothing works. I've used *align-items* but they do not move.

this is my html code:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  /*FLEX*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

header .youtube nav a span {
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

header .menu nav a span {
  padding: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

header .bloque nav a span {
  line-height: 50px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

header .bloque nav img {
  line-height: 50px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 50;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="menu">

    <nav>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-menu"></span></a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="youtube">
    <nav>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-youtube"></span>YouTube</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button type="submit">
       <span class="icon-magnifying-glass"></span>
      </button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div class="bloque">
    <nav>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-camera"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-grid"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-forward"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-globe"></span></a>
      <img src="guía.png" width="100">
    </nav>
    <div/>
</header>
```

when I use *justify-content:Space-round*, the items are placed the way I want to, but not properly spaced between them.  But for some strange reason when I use *align-item:flex-end* they are arranged like in the pic related. how do I solve this? any advice?

Comment: they are on the left!!

Comment: no, they are in the middle of the header, they can be further than that

Comment: look at your code! there's nothing in the middle.  but i can see it in the image if that's what you are talking about?

Comment: I think you mean to align them to the **right** not **left**

Comment: try To add   `justify-content: flex-end;` to the `header` tag

Answer (score 1):

To align items within the `header` tag you need to add `justify-content: flex-end;` to the header to read more about it [Check this site](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  /*FLEX*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /* justify-content: flex-end;*/  /*uncomment to align left*/
  align-items: center; /* to vertical align items */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

header .youtube nav a span {
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

/* header .menu nav a span {
  padding: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
} */

header .bloque nav a span {
  line-height: 50px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

header .bloque nav img {
  line-height: 50px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 50;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="menu">

    <nav>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-menu"></span></a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="youtube">
    <nav>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-youtube"></span>YouTube</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button type="submit">
       <span class="icon-magnifying-glass"></span>
      </button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div class="bloque">
    <nav>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-camera"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-grid"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-forward"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="icon-globe"></span></a>
      <img src="guía.png" width="100">
    </nav>
    <div/>
</header>
```

Comment: sorry for answering this late, I was working. but this doesnt solve the problen either. I copy-pasted your code in my .css and it doesnt work.

Comment: then the problem is not coming from the code you added. double check and inspect your code with developer tool.

Comment: the only warning it shows is The key "width-device-widht" is not recognized and ignored.